# Can this retailer be successfully sued for false arrest, false imprisonment or other tort?

Tags: united-states, tort, false-arrest

Here is a [Youtube recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKvHSRRjV0I) (2:00 to 3:00 minutes) where a defense lawyer related the story of a client accused of stealing by a retailer. The retailer's personnel stopped and questioned the woman (fair enough). But then they detained her for several hours and never let her go to the bathroom, despite repeated requests. To make matters worse, the detaining officers invited other store employees to observe the woman's distress when she urinated all over herself.

My understanding is that the store may take "reasonable" measures under the circumstances, such as taking the woman's name, address and other relevant "pedigree" information, so they can issue a notice of appearance. Under certain circumstances, they can call the police, and detain the person a reasonable time for the police to arrive. But I would characterize the measures that they actually took as being "extrajudicial." Can the victim of such treatment sue the retailer with some hope of prevailing, and if so, under what laws/charges?

Comment: Can you make it clearer that the story is an anecdote rather than a factual story?  Hes trying to sell his services here, of course hes going to play up that not only can he get you off but he can get you even...

Comment: @Moo: I believe this to be a true story. I don't think that a lawyer would "make up" this example. All in a day's work. He did not say he could get people "even." I was the one who made that point.

Comment: He related a fact pattern, and if for nothing else, the hypothetical, we need to take it as true. On a different note: A lawyer should be expected a higher moral character than average.